# ID3 over audio streaming?

Tags: ios, audio, streaming, id3

I've used [AudioStreamer courtesy Matt](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/06/revisiting-old-post-streaming-and.html)

I need to extract id3 metadata and display the current song playing.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mention "current song playing", I assume you are trying to play a stream, probably from SHOUTcast or Icecast.  These streams don't have ID3 data encoded... they use a separate mechanism.

This is fully detailed here:  http://www.smackfu.com/stuff/programming/shoutcast.html

And here:  [Pulling Track Info From an Audio Stream Using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911062/pulling-track-info-from-an-audio-stream-using-php/4914538#4914538)