# Export streaming info (sam broadcaster+icecast)

Tags: streaming, broadcast, icecast

I have a e-radio into my site
The uploading from audio room to server (few measures long-yes i have physiccal access to my server) uses sam broadcaster with mp3 encoded (maybe i must use ogg encoding).
The streaming from server to clients uses icecast2 server (debian machine lenny )

Well, i have two questions:

1)What player(s) is the best practice for embeding audio streaming into my page?
2)How can i catch song info (artist-tile,etc)?
Into icecast page i can see this info, so there is a way to export it to the page..
One friend uses cURl from php and then write this info into a file.But he didn't tell me details...
For preview mode i use windows media player

```
<OBJECT ID="MediaPlayer1" CLASSID="CLSID:22d6f312-b0f6-11d0-94ab-0080c74c7e95" CODEBASE="http://activex.microsoft.com/activex/controls/mplayer/en/nsmp2inf.cab# Version=5,1,52,701" STANDBY="Loading Microsoft Windows® Media Player components..." TYPE="application/x-oleobject" width="280" height="65">
<param name="fileName" value="http://dap.ntua.gr:8123/live.m3u">
<param name="animationatStart" value="true">
<param name="transparentatStart" value="true">
<param name="autoStart" value="true">
<param name="showControls" value="true">
<param name="Volume" value="300">
<embed type="application/x-mplayer2" pluginspage="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/" src="http://dap.ntua.gr:8123/live.m3u" name="MediaPlayer1" width=280 height=65 autostart=1 showcontrols=1 volume=-300>
</OBJECT>
```

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Web-Based SHOUTcast/Icecast Player

There are many available, but the one I've found to be most reliable is Minicaster.

http://www.draftlight.net/dnex/mp3player/minicaster/free/

It has plenty of ways to control it via JavaScript, so you don't need to use its interface.  (It certainly isn't the best looking, but gets around the memory leak issue with Flash.)

### Getting Metadata From Stream

See these questions:

- [Pulling Track Info From an Audio Stream Using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911062/pulling-track-info-from-an-audio-stream-using-php/4914538#4914538)
- [ID3 over audio streaming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6049128/id3-over-audio-streaming/6049953#6049953)
- [ICY metadata support with ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8339698/icy-metadata-support-with-ffmpeg/8342918#8342918)