# How to get metadata from a Shout cast streaming radio

Tags: android, metadata, media-player, shoutcast, internet-radio

I have written the codes for streaming the shout cast net radio. I have no idea about retrieving metadata of currently streaming songs.Can anyone provide a tutorial link or steps involved in this??

Comment: [Try searching](http://www.smackfu.com/stuff/programming/shoutcast.html) next time.

Comment: no links provides clear view it

Comment: @user3322681 The SmackFu reference Michael linked to is one of the better explanations out there.  What are your specific questions?  You might find my answer here helpful:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911062/pulling-track-info-from-an-audio-stream-using-php/4914538#4914538  While it's for PHP, the general concept is identical in any language.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Receiving Info of a ShoutCast stream on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865199/receiving-info-of-a-shoutcast-stream-on-android)