# Getting Metadata from shoutcast iOS programming

Tags: iphone, ios, metadata, shoutcast, webradio

Hello I am trying to parse Shoutcast radio's metadata in iOS.

After trying many submitted solutions, I end up with a piece of code that is still giving me error

**Response String: ICY 404 Resource Not Found
icy-notice1:
SHOUTcast Distributed Network Audio Server/Linux v1.9.8

icy-notice2:The resource requested was not found**

the code im trying to parse metadata

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://relay.181.fm:8052/7.html"];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:15.0];

   [request addValue:@"1" forHTTPHeaderField:@"icy-metadata"];
   [request addValue:@"Winamp 5/3" forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];
   [request addValue:@"audio/mpeg" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];

NSString* responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"Response String: %@", responseString);
```

any ideas about problem, thanks for helping

Answer (score 4):

Not all SHOUTcast servers allow access to `7.html`.  There are two other ways to get that data.

The XML data for SHOUTcast is generally available, but requires the server's password.  You can request it using `/admin.cgi?mode=viewxml&page=4`.

You can also read the metadata right out of the stream.  This is more cumbersome, but entirely possible, and not too difficult.  See this answer for details:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/4914538/362536

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for those who can't/doesn't want to read metadata from stream.
Its the easiest solution I have seen.

http://www.fvalente.org/blog/2012/03/15/shoutcast-metadata-the-easy-way/

Brad says in the post above

> Not all SHOUTcast servers allow access to 7.html.

so it is better to check if the server you want to get metadata has /7.html page

Comment: For what it's worth, I've had problems with 7.html not being served as UTF-8, leading to crap characters when I parse it. played.html doesn't give me that problem.

Answer (score 0):

the current song is also displayed on the page /played.html but it works in a web browser along with /7.html. But when i tried in fiddler2 on a windows machine i got the ICY 404 resource not found error