# Title of current icecast streamed song

Tags: c#, title, icecast

i've readed some question,but not one solved me.
i've maked a simple client to read soundstream by icecast2 server.
i read sound sound with:

```
    a = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();
    a.URL = "http://radiolink:8000/music";
    a.controls.play();
```

it's works and i ear music.
now i want to read title of current song.
i've found here i have to create a request like:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://radiolink:8000/music");

            request.Headers.Clear();

            request.Headers.Add("GET", " HTTP/1.0");
            request.UserAgent = "WinampMPEG/5.09";

            request.Headers.Add("Icy-MetaData", "1");
            request.KeepAlive = true;

            WebResponse fifo = request.GetResponse();


            Console.WriteLine(fifo.Headers);
```

Whit thath code console write only output (`content-type=audio-mpg`).
Can help me,and put me in the right way to read data correctly?

// solved frist part.
now i recive thath:

> icy-br: 128,128 ice-audio-info:
>   ice-samplerate=44100;ice-bitrate=128;ice-channels=2 icy-description:
>   radio fff icy-genre: Various icy-name: 
>   RADIO icy-pub: 0 icy-url: http://url.com icy-metaint:
>   16000 Cache-Control: no-cache Content-Type: audio/mpeg

how to read other metadata?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The metadata for SHOUTcast/Icecast streams is not in the headers, but in the actual stream itself.

That `icy-metaint: 16000` header you have is the key.  Every 16,000 bytes, you will get a metadata block.  The first byte in that block indicates metadata length.  Multiply its value by 16 to get the length in bytes.  Once you do that, you will end up with something like this:

```
StreamTitle='Awesome Trance Mix - DI.fm';StreamUrl=''
```

It will be padded at the end by null bytes until you reach the length of the block.

I have answered the same question here for PHP, but the concept is the same no matter what language:  [Pulling Track Info From an Audio Stream Using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911062/pulling-track-info-from-an-audio-stream-using-php/4914538#4914538)

Comment: try to understanding socket connection like your link.thank you.i tell you result next time

Comment: @devilkkw, You don't need to make a direct socket connection.  Your web request will do just fine.  The important part is that when you receive the response body from the stream server, that you split out the metadata from the actual stream.  I recommend using a packet sniffer, such as Wireshark, and looking at the stream.  Every 16,000 bytes, you will see the metablock I am talking about.

Comment: any sample of do it in c#?

Comment: @devilkkw, No, sorry.  Just take your incoming byte array, and after 16,000 bytes, read the next byte for length, take the metablock and put it in its own byte array, parse it, then read another 16,000 bytes and do it all again.

Comment: @devilkkw, With what specifically?  I don't have Visual Studio handy at the moment.  If you have a specific question, such as how to read byte arrays from an HTTP response, I suggest posting a different question for the specific issue you are trying to solve.