# Title of icecast stream (without status.xsl)

Tags: python, django, stream, icecast, internet-radio

I try to have the title (artist - song) for some icecast streams.
There are lot of discussion about it here and most of them just check the status.xsl (like Icecast Now Playing PHP script does).
But :
- lot of stream does not allow another script to read this file (for example
                                   `http://95.81.147.3/status.xsl?mount=/fip/all/fiphautdebit.mp3`         ) 
- as ePirat says a lot, it is not safe to parse html like this. But he proposes a solution only when we have access to the server.

From what I read : [there is metadata in icecast stream itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14540380/title-of-current-icecast-streamed-song)  but the solution give works only for shoutcast. So as [for this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14540380/title-of-current-icecast-streamed-song).
The closest thing i found is [this code review](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14540380/title-of-current-icecast-streamed-song) but although the title says icecast i just see shoutcast code with the Icy-MetaData  check.

This [very complete link](http://jicyshout.sourceforge.net/oreilly-article/java-streaming-mp3-pt2/java-streaming-mp3-pt2.html) can be useful (The out-of-band standards  section) but it is explained that is does not work still.

The question is basically : in order to get the Artist - song information,  how to read metadata of an icecast stream, when : 
- I'm not admin of the server 
- I don't want / can't parse the status.xsl  ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: The answer I gave in the question you linked to works for SHOUTcast and Icecast streams.  They use the exact same metadata method.  If you are unable to implement, I have an API that will return the metadata nicely in JSON.  You can access it here:  http://audiopump.co/accounts/products/manage/api

Comment: link from @Brad not working anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Icecast 2.4 the preferred way to get machine readable meta-data about the streams running through a server is *status-json.xsl*. This JSON API is default enabled on all installations.

If status-json.xsl returns a 404, then the server administrator has consciously chosen to disable access. In such a case and in case of old Icecast installations (2.3.x) that won't be retrofitted with the JSON API (it would be enough for the administrator to copy *status-json.xsl* and *xml2json.xslt* to the *web* directory) the approach of trying to parse the stream itself for metadata is an ugly but possible one. One has to wonder though if the administrator has chosen to disallow metadata access, if they are OK in general with use of their stream beyond simple listening.

Comment: Yeah, that message also appears if the file is not there. In this case easily confirmed by looking at http://pub8.radiotunes.com/server_version.xsl - which reveals that this is 2.3.3-kh7. It would only have this if someone copied the files manually to the webroot of Icecast.