# Show current song information from html5 audio stream (in Meteor app)

Tags: html, audio, meteor, html5-audio, internet-radio

I'm working on an HTML5 radio player in Meteorjs. See http://radio.meteor.com/ or http://github.com/guaka/radio-meteor

I want to display the song that's currently playing. How can I do that?

I'm not sure if resorting to server side would be a great idea as the server would have to fetch metadata for a growing number of streams (I want to allow people to add more channels).

Browsers compatibility is not that much of an issue, as long as it will work in Phonegap. I don't care about all browsers (i.e. IE) as long as I can make it fails gracefully.

I think [Pulling Track Info From an Audio Stream Using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911062/pulling-track-info-from-an-audio-stream-using-php/4914538#4914538) might be an answer than can work for Meteor (server side).

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible via filereader on the client end, browser compatibility would be a bit of trouble.

Have a look at:
http://ericbidelman.tumblr.com/post/8343485440/reading-mp3-id3-tags-in-javascript

Comment: I had seen this but as this is working on an input tag and a specific file I'm afraid this is not going to help with fetching ID3 tags from radio stream.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not actual now, but can help somebody else. I use [this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-internet-radio) package  to getting metadata about streaming audio

Comment: please add some content from the link