# How to get additional data from audio mp3 stream

Tags: ios, audio, mp3, metadata, audio-streaming

I'm currently developing iOS app for streaming audio for radio station, through mp3 file format.
I'm using AVPlayer and it is working like a charm!
In that stream (in mp3 file) server is also sending text data, more specifically title of song and name of the artist.

My questions are
 1. how to get that text data from continuous stream? in other words: how to approach problem of cutting mp3 stream into slices and get text data?
 2. which objects should I use? NSMutableData for example?
 3. which solution is better: slicing stream and getting that text or another service on server which return xml/json with title and artist of a current song played on radio?

Comment: This might help you figure out how to get that metadata (assuming it is in the stream SHOUTcast-style):  http://stackoverflow.com/a/4914538/362536  It's for a different language, but the concepts are the same.

Comment: It's ICEcast but thank you, know I now where and what I need to search

Comment: No problem!  Icecast and SHOUTcast use the same meta format, so if you are searching around, you can treat them as the same.  (SHOUTcast v2 has some differences, but is compatible with v1 which is identical to Icecast.)

Comment: yeeey :) this is great news!

Comment: related questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18172806/find-and-apply-metadata-tags-in-single-continuous-mp3-file and my own: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15444262/show-current-song-information-from-html5-audio-stream-in-meteor-app#