# PHP script to extract artist & title from Shoutcast/Icecast stream

Tags: php, audio-streaming, shoutcast, icecast

I found a script which can extract the artist & title name from an Icecast or Shoutcast stream.
I want the script to update automatically when a song changed, at the moment its working only when i execute it. I'm new to PHP so any help will be appreciated.
Thanks!

```
define('CRLF', "\r\n");

class streaminfo{
public $valid = false;
public $useragent = 'Winamp 2.81';

protected $headers = array();
protected $metadata = array();

public function __construct($location){
    $errno = $errstr = '';
    $t = parse_url($location);
    $sock = fsockopen($t['host'], $t['port'], $errno, $errstr, 5);
    $path = isset($t['path'])?$t['path']:'/';
    if ($sock){
        $request = 'GET '.$path.' HTTP/1.0' . CRLF . 
            'Host: ' . $t['host'] . CRLF . 
            'Connection: Close' . CRLF . 
            'User-Agent: ' . $this->useragent . CRLF . 
            'Accept: */*' . CRLF . 
            'icy-metadata: 1'.CRLF.
            'icy-prebuffer: 65536'.CRLF.
            (isset($t['user'])?'Authorization: Basic '.base64_encode($t['user'].':'.$t['pass']).CRLF:'').
            'X-TipOfTheDay: Winamp "Classic" rulez all of them.' . CRLF . CRLF;
        if (fwrite($sock, $request)){
            $theaders = $line = '';
            while (!feof($sock)){ 
                $line = fgets($sock, 4096); 
                if('' == trim($line)){
                    break;
                }
                $theaders .= $line;
            }
            $theaders = explode(CRLF, $theaders);
            foreach ($theaders as $header){
                $t = explode(':', $header); 
                if (isset($t[0]) && trim($t[0]) != ''){
                    $name = preg_replace('/[^a-z][^a-z0-9]*/i','', strtolower(trim($t[0])));
                    array_shift($t);
                    $value = trim(implode(':', $t));
                    if ($value != ''){
                        if (is_numeric($value)){
                            $this->headers[$name] = (int)$value;
                        }else{
                            $this->headers[$name] = $value;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if (!isset($this->headers['icymetaint'])){
                $data = ''; $metainterval = 512;
                while(!feof($sock)){
                    $data .= fgetc($sock);
                    if (strlen($data) >= $metainterval) break;
                }
               $this->print_data($data);
                $matches = array();
                preg_match_all('/([\x00-\xff]{2})\x0\x0([a-z]+)=/i', $data, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
               preg_match_all('/([a-z]+)=([a-z0-9\(\)\[\]., ]+)/i', $data, $matches, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
               echo '<pre>';var_dump($matches);echo '</pre>';
                $title = $artist = '';
                foreach ($matches[0] as $nr => $values){
                  $offset = $values[1];
                  $length = ord($values[0]{0}) + 
                            (ord($values[0]{1}) * 256)+ 
                            (ord($values[0]{2}) * 256*256)+ 
                            (ord($values[0]{3}) * 256*256*256);
                  $info = substr($data, $offset + 4, $length);
                  $seperator = strpos($info, '=');
                  $this->metadata[substr($info, 0, $seperator)] = substr($info, $seperator + 1);
                    if (substr($info, 0, $seperator) == 'title') $title = substr($info, $seperator + 1);
                    if (substr($info, 0, $seperator) == 'artist') $artist = substr($info, $seperator + 1);
                }
                $this->metadata['streamtitle'] = $artist . ' - ' . $title;
            }else{
                $metainterval = $this->headers['icymetaint'];
                $intervals = 0;
                $metadata = '';
                while(1){
                    $data = '';
                    while(!feof($sock)){
                        $data .= fgetc($sock);
                        if (strlen($data) >= $metainterval) break;
                    }
                    //$this->print_data($data);
                    $len = join(unpack('c', fgetc($sock))) * 16;
                    if ($len > 0){
                        $metadata = str_replace("\0", '', fread($sock, $len));
                        break;
                    }else{
                        $intervals++;
                        if ($intervals > 100) break;
                    }
                }
                $metarr = explode(';', $metadata);
                foreach ($metarr as $meta){
                    $t = explode('=', $meta);
                    if (isset($t[0]) && trim($t[0]) != ''){
                        $name = preg_replace('/[^a-z][^a-z0-9]*/i','', strtolower(trim($t[0])));
                        array_shift($t);
                        $value = trim(implode('=', $t));
                        if (substr($value, 0, 1) == '"' || substr($value, 0, 1) == "'"){
                            $value = substr($value, 1);
                        }
                        if (substr($value, -1) == '"' || substr($value, -1) == "'"){
                            $value = substr($value, 0, -1);
                        }
                        if ($value != ''){
                            $this->metadata[$name] = $value;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            fclose($sock);
            $this->valid = true;
        }else echo 'unable to write.';
    }else echo 'no socket '.$errno.' - '.$errstr.'.';
}


public function print_data($data){
    $data = str_split($data);
    $c = 0;
    $string = '';
    echo "<pre>\n000000 ";
    foreach ($data as $char){
        $string .= addcslashes($char, "\n\r\0\t");
        $hex = dechex(join(unpack('C', $char)));
        if ($c % 4 == 0) echo ' ';
        if ($c % (4*4) == 0 && $c != 0){
          foreach (str_split($string) as $s){
            //echo " $string\n";
            if (ord($s) < 32 || ord($s) > 126){
              echo '\\'.ord($s);
            }else{
              echo $s;
            }
          }
          echo "\n";
          $string = '';
          echo str_pad($c, 6, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT).'  ';
        }
        if (strlen($hex) < 1) $hex = '00';
        if (strlen($hex) < 2) $hex = '0'.$hex;
          echo $hex.' ';
        $c++;
    }
    echo "  $string\n</pre>";
}

public function __get($name){
    if (isset($this->metadata[$name])){
        return $this->metadata[$name];
    }
    if (isset($this->headers[$name])){
        return $this->headers[$name];
    }
    return null;
 }
}

$t = new streaminfo('http://64.236.34.196:80/stream/1014'); // get metadata


echo Meta Interval: $t->icymetaint;
echo Current Track: $t->streamtitle;
```

Comment: Thanks for this script. I just kept finding ones that parsed the stream data HTML page, which are subject to breaking with future versions of Icecast/Shoutcast.  (Reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25268050/php-icecast-now-playing-script-is-not-working/25344443#25344443)

Comment: The last two echo commands were throwing an error.  To correct the error I changed them to:  echo "Meta Interval:  ".$t->icymetaint;
echo "\n";
echo 'Current Track:  '.$t->streamtitle;

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run the PHP script to keep your meta data up to date (I'm assuming you're making a website and using html audio tags here) you can use the ontimeupdate event with an ajax function. If you're not you probably should look up your audio playback documentation for something similar.

```
<audio src="http://ip:port/;" ontimeupdate="loadXMLDoc()">
```

You can find a great example here http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp

You want to use the PHP echo function all the relevant information at once using one php variable at the very end of your script.

```
<?php ....
$phpVar=$streamtitle;
$phpVar2=$streamsong;
$result="I want my string to look like this: <br> {$phpVar} {$phpVar2}";
echo $result;
?>
```

and then use the function called by the .onreadystatechange to modify the particular elements you want on your website by using the .resonseText (this will contain the same content as your PHP script's echo).

Answer (score 0):

You will need to constantly query the stream at a set interval to find when the song changes.

This can be best done by scheduling a [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) job.
If on Windows, you should use the [Windows Task Scheduler](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569)

Comment: how can I set interval with PHP?

Comment: can i use cron on a windows machine?

Comment: @YosiBenSimon: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132971/what-is-the-windows-version-of-cron

Answer (score -1):

After SCOURING the web for 4 hours, this is the only Shoutcast metadata script I've found that works! Thankyou.

To run this constantly, why not use a setInterval combined with jQuery's AJAX call?

```
<script>
$(function() {
    setInterval(getTrackName,16000);
});

function getTrackName() {
    $.ajax({
    url: "track_name.php"
    })
    .done(function( data ) {
    $( "#results" ).text( data );
    });
}
</script>
```

Also your last couple 'echo' lines were breaking the script for me. Just put quotes around the Meta Interval, etc....