# How to fetch Metadata from shoutcast radio channel for Windowsphone?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, shoutcast, internet-radio

I like to develop a Windowsphone 8/7 internet radio app which streams the audio file from shoutcast radio channel.For that I need to extract metadata from the streaming.Now I am wondering about how to extract metadata from the stream.

Comment: See my answer here:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/4914538/362536  It's for a different language, but the concept is exactly the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a custom MediaStreamSource implementation. This way you'll have complete control on what data is received from the network, and what data is fed to the OS-provided media codecs.

Unfortunately this task is hard. Here's the document outlining some technical challenges I've encountered (and solved):
http://const.me/SkyFM/technical.aspx