# streaming media RTP and Shoutcast

Tags: rtp, shoutcast

I try to create an audio streaming server in java.  There are several protocols to stream media like RTP, and I'm a little confused with all protocols.

What are the differences between RTP and Shoutcast? Do they use TCP, UDP or HTTP? Does anyone have a clear explanation on this point?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SHOUTcast and Icecast use a client protocol very similar to HTTP.  (In fact, Icecast is compliant with HTTP as spec'ed in RFC2616, and most HTTP clients work with SHOUTcast without modification.)  A request comes in for a stream, and they return the stream audio data in the same way as an HTTP response, along with some extra metadata.

```
GET /radioreddit/main_mp3_128k HTTP/1.1

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With
Server: AudioPump Server/0.8.1 (http://audiopump.co)
Content-Type: audio/mpeg
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Sat, 15 Aug 2009 22:00:00 GMT
Connection: close
icy-genre: Indie,Rock,Talk
icy-name: Radio Reddit - Main
icy-pub: 1
icy-url: http://radioreddit.com
Date: Tue, 05 Aug 2014 13:40:55 GMT
```

In this example, the response is purely HTTP.  If this were a SHOUTcast server, instead of seeing `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` in the status line, you would see `ICY 200 OK`.  The headers that start with `icy-` are those that describe the station.  Sometimes there are more, sometimes they don't exist at all.  A client would be able to play MP3 data from this station as-is.

Now, sometimes the client will request metadata to be sent in the stream.  This allows the player to tell you what is playing.  A client does this by sending a `icy-metadata: 1` header.  The server will respond with `icy-metaint: 8192`, which means that every 8192 bytes there will be a chunk of metadata.  You can [read more about the format of that metadata on a previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4914538/362536).

I should also note that this form of streaming is often called HTTP Progressive Streaming.  To the client, it's no different than playing a media file as it is being downloaded... except that the file is infinite in size.

Now, RTP is a protocol used in conjunction with RTSP.  RTP is the actual media data where RTSP is used for control.  These protocols are much more complicated, as they are meant for true streaming.  That is, if the client can't handle the bandwidth, they can drop down to a lower bitrate.  If the client needs to control the remote, that can be done as well.  This complexity comes at a price.  The servers are complicated to implement.  There isn't great client compatibility.

A couple years back when I started to create my own streaming server, I had asked myself the same question.  Do I implement a real streaming protocol that has not-so-great client support and will take a long time to figure out, or do I implement a protocol that everything can play, and is easy to build for.  I went the HTTP route.

These days, you should also consider [HLS](https://developer.apple.com/streaming/) which is nothing more than chunking your source stream into pieces at several bitrates and serving it over HTTP.  If the client wants to change bitrates due to lack of bandwidth, it can just start requesting the low bitrate chunks.  HLS also doesn't have great client support, but it is getting better.  I suspect it will surpass all others for media delivery on websites in time.

Answer (score 0):

The comparison between `RTP` (a protocol) and `Shoutcast` (an application) is not applicable.

`RTP` is the Internet standard for transporting multimedia over `IP`.

It is an application layer protocol, so  `RTP` can be transported over `TCP` or `UDP`, depending on the nature of the communication. Also, it needs to be implemented by an application before it can be of any use, much like `HTTP` has to be implemented by a browser so that a user can access web pages. When implemented by an application, it is used for specifying the media format, numerous other characteristics and basic control information (via `RTSP`).

`Shoutcast` is a streaming application created by `Nullsoft` (the `Winamp` authors). It uses its own protocols for media transportation and can run over either TCP or UDP.

There are numerous other **streaming protocols**, so a [Google](http://www.google.com/) search on the subject is, as usually, a good idea. [Wikipedia](http://www.wikipedia.org) also hosts a [comparison of streaming media systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_streaming_media_systems).

Comment: Thx.
One more question : is Shoutcast use RTP ?

Comment: There is not much documentation on that. Maybe not in the standardized form (i.e., they may be using some proprietary extension). Try Google for more information on streaming protocols (e.g., here is one site with a brief explanation of a few: http://www.garymcgath.com/streamingprotocols.html).

Comment: Sorry, but there are two SHOUTcast protocols (source client protocol, and the protocol for listening often referred to as ICY which is nearly the same as HTTP).  Both are extensively documented, and only run over TCP, not UDP.

Comment: "Both are extensively documented" ... ok, but where ?
I'm looking for java example , but find nothing.

Comment: @asicfr Protocol documentation is all over... I added some links in my answer above.  An implementation sample for Java... I'm not sure of since I am not a Java programmer.  It isn't a difficult protocol, so I would look for sockets usage in Java and go from there.