# SHOUTcast - Polling 7.html

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, audio-streaming, shoutcast

I am not a fan of polling for information and suspect there is a better way of achieveing what I want.

I am playing an internet radio stream with Android's MediaPlayer. I can find out which tune is playing and by which artist by requesting the 7.html file at the server's address.

My questions are:

1. Is there a way to receive a notification when a new song begins
   to play?
2. Must I poll the 7.html to find out what is now playing?
3. If I do have to poll, is there any way in which I can determine
   the duration of the current song so I can poll only when a new song
   starts?

I guess if I had a low-level stream processing function of my own, I could tell when the song changes because I would receive the meta-data, but I'm not sure how to do that with the Android MediaPlayer class.

Comment: Yes, the `7.html` method is not reliable, and and is increasingly unavailable.  As you have suggested, you will have to write a stream demuxer to split the audio and metadata components apart.  I'm not an Android dev so I can't suggest a way to do this, but I have seen classes around here on Stack Overflow that handle the metadata.  I did write up instructions on how to do this in PHP.  Perhaps it could be translated:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911062/pulling-track-info-from-an-audio-stream-using-php/4914538#4914538

Comment: @Brad: Thanks Brad. I have some C# code that does just that.. I'll just poll every 10 seconds for now until I feel the need to write my own stream player in Android.

Comment: Did you every try to get the `Metatags` as described here ( http://uniqueculture.net/2010/11/stream-metadata-plain-java/ )? I know that SHOUTcast just updated their API, but I was only working with the iOS version. We use the tag `StreamTitle` which usually to 98% is `ARTIST - TITLE`. You just have use regex if artist contains an "-"...

Comment: @longilong: Thanks for the reply.. Seems like ages ago since I did this. I got it working OK using polling which was annoying (on Android) but whatever I did on iOS worked fine. I think the player abstraction in iOS must filter out the meta data contained within the stream whereas Android did not. Can't believe it was only Nov when I asked about this. Seems a lifetime ago :)

Answer (score 0):

Haha, seven years after commenting I finally had to implement this :-D I want a tumbleweed badge for this ;-)

1. Not to my knowledge
2. Yes
3. Not to my knowledge, but polling timers between 30-60 seconds should be fine. At the beginning I wanted to reduce network traffic for users, but this is irrelevant if you are streaming radio at the same time :-D

And here my quick and dirty solution, just in case someone needs it. There are some custom classes in the example, but you ll get the point

```kotlin
import androidx.core.text.HtmlCompat
import de.jahpress.android.main.L
import de.jahpress.android.main.MAX_REQUEST_FOR_SHOUTCAST_TRACK_INFO
import de.jahpress.android.service.Data
import de.jahpress.android.service.radio.model.BaseStation
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient
import okhttp3.Request
import java.util.*
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit
import kotlin.concurrent.thread

class ShoutCastTrackInfoManager {

    private val timeOut = 5L
    private val pollingIntervalMs = 60_000L
    private var updateTimer: Timer? = null
    private var trackInfoThread: Thread? = null

    private var invalidTrackInfoCounter = 0

    //will ask track info only one time (select station in my use case)
    fun updateTrackInfoFor(station: BaseStation, resultCallback: (info: String?) -> Unit) {
        L.d("TrackInfo: Get title info for ${station.getStationName()}")
        invalidTrackInfoCounter = 0
        stopTrackInfoPolling()
        requestTrackInfoFromShoutcast(station, resultCallback)
    }

    //will start track info polling (if station is playing)
    fun startTrackInfoPolling(station: BaseStation) {
        L.d("TrackInfo: Get title info for ${station.getStationName()}")
        stopTrackInfoPolling()
        updateTimer = Timer()
        updateTimer?.schedule(object : TimerTask() {
            override fun run() {
                requestTrackInfoFromShoutcast(station, null)
            }
        }, 0, pollingIntervalMs)
    }

    fun stopTrackInfoPolling() {
        trackInfoThread?.let {
            L.d("TrackInfo: Stopping current title update for stream")
            it.interrupt()
        }
        updateTimer?.cancel()
    }

    private fun requestTrackInfoFromShoutcast(
        station: BaseStation,
        resultCallback: ((info: String?) -> Unit)?
    ) {
        if (invalidTrackInfoCounter >= MAX_REQUEST_FOR_SHOUTCAST_TRACK_INFO) {
            L.d("TrackInfo: $MAX_REQUEST_FOR_SHOUTCAST_TRACK_INFO invalid stream titles. Sto...")
            invalidTrackInfoCounter = 0
            stopTrackInfoPolling()
            Data.currentTitleInfo = null  //reset track info
            return
        }

        trackInfoThread = thread {
            try {
                var trackInfo: String? = null
                get7HtmlFromStream(station)?.let {
                    L.d("TrackInfo: Request track info at $it")
                    val request = Request.Builder().url(it).build()
                    val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
                        .connectTimeout(timeOut, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .writeTimeout(timeOut, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .readTimeout(timeOut, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .build()

                    val response = okHttpClient.newCall(request).execute()

                    if (response.isSuccessful) {
                        val result = response.body?.string()
                        trackInfo = extractTrackInfoFrom7Html(result)

                        if (trackInfo != null) {
                            Data.currentTitleInfo = trackInfo
                        }
                    }
                    response.close()
                }

                resultCallback?.invoke(trackInfo)

            } catch (e: Exception) {
                L.e(e)
                resultCallback?.invoke(null)
                stopTrackInfoPolling()
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Will create Shoutcast 7.html which is located at stream url.
     *
     * For example: http://66.55.145.43:7473/stream
     * 7.html at http://66.55.145.43:7473/7.html
     */
    private fun get7HtmlFromStream(station: BaseStation): String? {
        val baseStreamUrl = station.getStreamUrl()
        L.w("Base url -> $baseStreamUrl")
        if (baseStreamUrl == null) return null

        val numberSlash = baseStreamUrl.count { c -> c == '/' }
        if (numberSlash <= 2) {
            return "$baseStreamUrl/7.html"
        }

        val startOfPath = station.getStreamUrl().indexOf("/", 8)
        val streamUrl = station.getStreamUrl().subSequence(0, startOfPath)
        return "$streamUrl/7.html"
    }

    /**
     * Will convert webpage to trackinfo. Therefore
     * 1. Remove all html-tags
     * 2. Get <body> content of webpage
     * 3. Extract and return trackinfo
     *
     * Trackinfo format is always like
     * "632,1,1943,2000,439,128,Various Artists - Dance to Dancehall"
     * so method will return everything after sixth "," comma character.
     *
     * Important:
     * - Shoutcast might return invalid html
     * - Site will return 404 error strings
     * - might be empty
     */
    private fun extractTrackInfoFrom7Html(html: String?): String? {
        L.i("Extract track info from ->  $html")
        if (html == null) return null
        val content = HtmlCompat.fromHtml(html, HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT).toString()
        val array = content.split(",")
        return if (array.size < 7) {
            null
        } else {
            var combinedTrackInfo = ""
            for (index in 6 until array.size) {
                combinedTrackInfo += "${array[index]} "
            }

            if (combinedTrackInfo.trim().isEmpty()) {
                return null
            }

            return combinedTrackInfo
        }
    }
}
```