# Trying to read and play live ShoutCast stream with C#

Tags: c#, shoutcast, internet-radio

I've been trying to find a way to play a live ShoutCast stream using C#. I've been researching the internet for that, and so far i have only found some ways for playing streams with fixed length, but i want to play a live radio station.

Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: Look for the specs and find out what kind of streaming protocol it uses and implement that accordingly.

Comment: I know how to implement the connection, i need information about how to read a continuous stream mp3 of data and play it.

Answer (score 1):

SHOUTcast streams are basically HTTP streams, but with a broken status line header.  Instead of `HTTP/1.1 200 OK`, you get `ICY 200 OK`.  From there, you can detect the format and codec from the `Content-Type` response header (such as `audio/mpeg`) and stream playback as the data comes in.

In addition to this, there is metadata interleaved into the stream.  This is optional but can be requested by adding the following header to your request:

`Icy-MetaData: 1`

Then in the response headers, you will see `Icy-MetaInt` to tell you how many bytes are between each metadata chunk.  See this post for more info on how to handle that metadata:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/4914538/362536