# Get ShoutCast/IceStream metadata with mp3spi1.9.5

Tags: java, connection

I am using **JLayer** to stream online radio music so a simple code for this is here:(Where **StreamPlayer** is a special implementation of **JLayer**)

//Radio Station URL example is http://radio.flex.ru:8000/radionami

```
/**
 * Plays the Given Online Stream
 * 
 * @param url
 *      <b> The Specified url you want to connect </b>
 * @throws IOException
 * @throws JavaLayerException
 */
public void playRadioStream(URL spec) {

    try {
        // Connection
        URLConnection urlConnection = spec.openConnection();

        // Connecting
        urlConnection.connect();

        // Try to play it
        StreamPlayer player = new StreamPlayer();

        player.open((urlConnection.getInputStream()));
        player.play();
    } catch (StreamPlayerException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

**The problem:**

I can't figure out how to retrieve information from this connection like the song is playing now from this Radio Station or the name of Station etc...The help is really appreciated!!

> **Edit:**

If you want you can use **JLayer** instead of **StreamPlayer** it will work ,although you have to run it on different Thread from the main app Thread.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4914538/1553851