# How to get data from online radio?

Tags: discord.js, internet-radio, webradio

I'm making Discord radio bot (In JavaScript) that streams online radios.I want to add now-playing command, but Idk how to recognize that song or where I can find metadata from that radio station. I want to add more than 10000 radio stations, but firstly I have to fix this...

Thx for every answer! (Also... Sorry for my english I'm from the Czech republic)

Comment: Probably each radio has a different protocol to communicate metadata.

Comment: What sort of stations?  Most "live" stations use ICY-style metadata in their stream.  (https://stackoverflow.com/a/4914538/362536)  Increasingly, you're seeing metadata in HLS and DASH streams.  A handful have a totally custom metadata setup.

Comment: You might want to include some of the code that you have and where you're getting the streams.

Comment: Here is a website from which I using radios - http://www.radio-browser.info/gui/#!/ and Im editing this https://github.com/Popzi/ilikeradio